# Solve $3y' + 6xy = 6e^{-x}$ where $y(0)=1$.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve $3y' + 6xy = 6e^{-x}$ where $y(0) = 1$. This is a first-order linear equation. Dividing by $3$ and multiplying by $e^{x^2}$, we have
$$
e^{x^2}y' + 2xe^{x^2}y = 2e^{x^2-x}.
$$
Thus, we have

$$
\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x^2}y) = 2e^{x^2-x}.
$$

Now, we have

$$
e^{x^2}y = 2\int e^{x^2-x}dx.
$$
How do I calculate this integral? The solution is supposedly $y(x) = (2x+1)e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: There must be a misprint in the original problem. Have you tried computing $3y^\prime+6xy$ for the supposed solution?

Comment: I believe the equation must be $3y' + 6xy = 6e^{-x^2}$ where $y(0) = 1$ and not the one you wrote above!

Comment: That does make more sense. I’ll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the reformulation of the given problem, we can proceed as follows in order to solve it:
\begin{align*}
3y' + 6xy = 6e^{-x^{2}} & \Longleftrightarrow y' + 2xy = 2e^{-x^{2}}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow e^{x^{2}}y' + 2xe^{x^{2}}y = 2\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (e^{x^{2}}y)' = 2\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow e^{x^{2}}y = 2x +c\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y(x) = 2xe^{-x^{2}} + ce^{-x^{2}}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps !

Answer (score 0):

The given solution was $y(x) = (2x+1)e^{-x^2}$. Supposing this is indeed the solution, we have

$$
3y' = -(12x^2 +6x - 6)e^{-x^2}.
$$

We also have

$$
6xy = (12x^2 -6x)e^{-x^2}.
$$

Thus, we have $3y' + 6xy = 6e^{-x^2}$, and indeed, the problem was misprinted. The problem should read "Solve $3y' + 6xy = 6e^{-x^2}$."